# DiG transfer fails with axfr options

Tags: shell, command-line, dns, dig

For testing purposes, I'm trying to get a list of all DNS records set for a domain, using [this method](https://serverfault.com/a/72504/152253).

This works:

```
root@cs:/# dig @nameserver domain

; <<>> DiG 9.9.2-P1 <<>> @nameserver domain
; (2 servers found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 32999
;; flags: qr aa; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;domain.           IN      A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
domain.    3600    IN      A       my-IP

;; Query time: 2 msec
;; SERVER: my-IPv6-IP-(I-think)
;; WHEN: Thu Jun 20 16:03:05 2013
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 83
```

However, when I add `axfr` to the command as is suggested in that answer on Server Fault (and all over the net), it fails:

```
root@cs:/# dig @ns1.transip.nl changeyourschool.nl axfr

; <<>> DiG 9.9.2-P1 <<>> @ns1.transip.nl changeyourschool.nl axfr
; (2 servers found)
;; global options: +cmd
; Transfer failed.
```

Why is this, and, more importantly, how can I get the full list of DNS records if this fails?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why this is, I don't know, but you can use this to get all the DNS records:

```
root@cs:/# dig google.com ANY +nostat +nocmd +nocomments

; <<>> DiG 9.9.2-P1 <<>> google.com ANY +nostat +nocmd +nocomments
;; global options: +cmd
;google.com.                    IN      ANY
google.com.             56328   IN      NS      ns4.google.com.
google.com.             56328   IN      NS      ns2.google.com.
google.com.             56328   IN      NS      ns1.google.com.
google.com.             56328   IN      NS      ns3.google.com.
ns4.google.com.         85545   IN      A       216.239.38.10
ns1.google.com.         85545   IN      A       216.239.32.10
ns3.google.com.         57402   IN      A       216.239.36.10
ns2.google.com.         85545   IN      A       216.239.34.10
```

The `+nostat`, `+nocmd` and `+nocomments` additions can be omitted, but reduce the useless output.

Comment: Zone transfers (axfr requests) have the purpose to replicate DNS databases across a set of DNS servers. Therefore the zone transfers are usually only allowed for the IP addresses of secondary (slave) name servers. Such a measure reduces load on the DNS master server.

Comment: `any` and `axfr` are not the same. `any` only requests records of the current host. `axfr` requests the whole zone infos of that host.

Answer (score 2):

Keelan's solution did not work for me.

What did work for me was a two step process (on Linux and Windows).

**Step one type:**

`dig ns google.com`

Where `google.com` is the domain of interest.

This returned a list of name servers such as:

```
ns1.google.com.         60      IN      A       216.239.32.10
```

**Step two type:**

`dig ns1.google.com google.com any`

Where `ns1.google.com` is the name server for the domain (found in step 1) and `google.com` is the domain of interest.

This yielded results such as:

```
google.com.             31335   IN      NS      ns4.google.com.
google.com.             31335   IN      NS      ns2.google.com.
google.com.             31335   IN      NS      ns3.google.com.
google.com.             59      IN      SOA     ns1.google.com. dns-admin.google.com. 1579113 7200 1800 1209600 300
google.com.             60      IN      A       216.58.220.142
google.com.             2251    IN      TXT     "v=spf1 include:_spf.google.com ip4:216.73.93.70/31 ip4:216.73.93.72/31 ~all"
google.com.             31335   IN      NS      ns1.google.com.
google.com.             185     IN      AAAA    2404:6800:4006:800::200e
```

Hope this helps. If it does not, you can always try: http://www.whois.com.au/whois/dns.html.

Comment: A collection of records the server is willing to release is quite different from a zone transfer.

Comment: You are right but if you look at OP objective he say " I'm trying to get a list of all DNS records set for a domain"... good point but I don't think I deserve a down vote.

Answer (score 1):

Like the answer you link to explains, the convention is to disallow the `axfr` command except for trusted peers.

If zone transfers are disabled, you can only get an approximate listing of hosts within a zone by guessing them, i.e. basically a dictionary attack. A well-maintained site will have measures in place to mitigate that approach as well.